# How to connect RTKQ with CreateSlice? No date in store from slice

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Main problem:  no datę in store from slice.

Description: I want to create shop. I used to RTKQ to fetch date from endpoint and slice to create shop cart (increase, decrease, remove, add etc).
Problem is that I can connect it to one working system. I read a lot that it is not recommended and you try to prevent from that thing. But I also read that this is possible.
I read the solution that I can put as extraReducers to slice, but I want know how to connect it by store.

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { setupListeners } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query";
import { DummyShopApi } from "./reducers/itemSlice";
import { cartSlice } from "./reducers/cartSlice";
import {reducerPath} from "./reducers/itemSlice";
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  card: cartSlice,
  [DummyShopApi.reducerPath]: DummyShopApi.reducer
});


export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(DummyShopApi.middleware),
});

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
setupListeners(store.dispatch);
```

Comment: You don't need any more "connecting". Every action in a Redux store goes to every reducer, and both reducers are in the same store. If you add an extraReducer for an action from RTKQ, that will trigger without any more connecting beyond that

Comment: But I do not see store at redux dev tool nor console.log. My redux register payload, and that's all.

Comment: If you don't see the dev tools or console.log, how do you know that something registers? Could you maybe show the code where things should happen, explain what you want to happen there and then explain what happens instead?

Comment: i solved the problem.. I do not put correct path. I should import as cartSlice without {}.

Answer (score 0):

it's common question and you could find the solution in documentation, but...))) I'll explain

When you have some query, what looks like:

```
export const pizzaApi = api.injectEndpoints({
      endpoints: (builder) => ({
            getPizzas: builder.Query<pizzasResponse, any>({
                  query: ({ sortBy }) => {
                        const sortBy1 = `sortBy=${sortBy ? sortBy : 'price'}`;
                            return {
                              url: `api?${sortBy1}`
                        };
                  }
            })
      })
});

export const { useGetPizzasQuery } = pizzaApi;
```

You get a 'queryHook' called useGetPizzasQuery. To add fetched pizzas from it to state (pizzaSlice), you should define extra reducer in your's slice:

```
extraReducers: (builder) => {
            builder
                .addMatcher(pizzaApi.endpoints.getPizzas.matchFulfilled, (state, action) => {
                        state.pizzas = action.payload.pizzas.content;
                  });
      }
```